# button created using Ajax Action Link does not load database data when button clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

Aim: Create a button on the index (home) page that load movies with a status of "View All" from data that has been seeded from database. The button, when clicked, does not direct the user to a different web page but enables the user to stay of the same web page. I created an Ajax.ActionLink on the Index View and created a _ViewAll view file which contains a foreach loop to produce a list of movies with status of "View All". The Controller contains a partialviewresult ViewAll () method that produces a list of movies with the status="View All".

Problem: when I click the "View All" button on the index website, no data is displayed/no movies with status=="View All" is loaded onto the same index page when "View All" button clicked.

Attempted Resolution: I have js unobtrusive and jquery scripts included on the _Layout view page. I have also followed many tutorials and can't seem to figure out what this issue is. Thank you for your time.

Here is my ViewAll method from StoreController:

```
    public ActionResult ViewAll ()
    {

        var movie = storeDB.Movies
                            .Include("MovieStatus")
                            .Where(g => g.MovieStatus.Status == "View All");
        ;
        return PartialView("_ViewAll", movie.ToList());
```

Here is my Index view:

```
  @ model  IEnumerable<Cinema1.Models.Movie>



  <p>   
  <div id="View All">


        @Ajax.ActionLink("Please Click", "ViewAll", "Store",
        new AjaxOptions
         {
           UpdateTargetId = "View All",
           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "GET"
         },
         new { @class = "btn btn-default" });


     </div>
  </p>
```

Here is my _ViewAll view:

```
 @model  IEnumerable<Cinema1.Models.Movie>

        <ul>
            @foreach (var Movies in Model)
            {
                <li>
                    @Movies.Title
                </li>
                <li>@Movies.MovieStatus.Status</li>
            }
        </ul>
```

Comment: Start by changing the element to `<div id="ViewAll">` and `UpdateTargetId = "ViewAll",` (no space) - Spaces are not valid in `id` attributes

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks it works! thank you for your time.